# Как правильно запросить код с другой странице в PHP ?

Tags: php, phpunit

Испытываю проблемы с запросами на код на других страницах .. 
Ознакамливаюсь с PHP ..

Почему ПХП не может найти класс ? Как правильно запрашивать код ? Вроде всё сделанно правильно , нечего не пойму ..

Прошу не советовать такие вещи как аутолоадер (Composer) так как сначала хочу написать на чистом ПХП ..

Создал Namespace и запросил с Require_once по пути :

> require_once **DIR**."../../classes/model/DBHandler.php";

```
<?php

 use data\User;
 use model\DBHandler;
 use PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase as TestCase;
 require_once __DIR__."../../classes/model/DBHandler.php";

 class ClassTester extends TestCase
{
   public function testExist(){
   $handler = new DBHandler();
   $exist = $handler->exist(new 
   User(320415904,"Maks","Burkov","Maks19880@"));
   if($exist){
       echo "User exist in database! ";
   }elseif(!$exist){
       echo "<pre>";
       echo "You need to register this user it is not exist! ";
       echo "</pre>";
   }
}

public function testLogin(){
    $handler = new DBHandler();
    $user = new User(320415904,"Maks","Burkov","Maks19880@");
    $exist = $handler->login($user);
    if($exist){
        echo "<pre>";
        echo "User "."{$user->getUserName()}"." exist in database! ";
        echo "</pre>";
    }elseif(!$exist){
        echo "<pre>";
        echo "You need to register this user "."{$usergetUserName()}"." it is not exist! ";
        echo "</pre>";
    }
}

public function testRegister(){
    $handler = new DBHandler();
    $user = new User(320415904,"Maks","Burkov","Maks19880@");
    $success = $handler->register($user);
    if($success){
        echo "<pre>";
        echo "User "."{$user->getUserName()}"." registered in database! 
     ";
        echo "</pre>";
    }
  }
}
```

Получаю ошибку :

> > Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/PHPUnitP/projectfiles/tests/classtester../../classes/model/DBHandler.php' (include_path='.:/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php') in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/PHPUnitP/projectfiles/tests/classtester/ClassTester.php on line 6

Моя структура проекта :

[image: Структура]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> /classteste**r../**../classes

Очевидно же, что пропущен один слеш. И, действительно

> `require_once __DIR__."../../classes/model/DBHandler.php";`

`__DIR__` возвращает каталог текущего скрипта без завершающего `/`. А Вы к нему добавляете еще две точки.

Должно быть так

```
require_once __DIR__ . "/../../classes/model/DBHandler.php";
```

Comment: Это не я , это PHP Strom автодополняет , уже не раз создавало мне проблемы ..

Comment: @Mekudad Но текст ошибки можно же читать?

Comment: Текст ошибки пишет что не находит .. Особо много это не помогает .

Comment: @Mekudad но пишет, что ищет